# Drawing a background image in IOS with OpenGL has poor quality

Tags: ios, opengl-es

When using open gl to draw background images, you typically have to use a texture and draw a quad.  When ever I've done that, I dont get a pixel perfect representation of my image.  Things like fine text gets blended badly.  In the past I've relied on canvas type drawing to make that nicer.  Is there a way to get the pixel perfect drawing of the canvas type bit blits with opengl es?

Comment: Generally, it works just fine if you're drawing a quad that ends up exactly the same number of pixels on screen as your image. Can you give an example of what you're trying and what your results look like?

Comment: I have blurry images in the past with OpenGLES. Turns out the devices uses scale ratio of 2.0 on retina displays so the app needed to explicitly tell OpenGL ES to use scale ratio of 2.0. Otherwise, it'll show a blurry image even with pixel for pixel mapping.

Comment: IOS starts all apps with a splash screen that I don't really control, I just provide the bitmap for it.  When the splash screen starts, it shows my splash image, using pixel perfect rendering since its a bitmap blit.  When my game starts, I want it to render the very same screen except a a few extra button appears.  Since my game is all openGL, I have to use textures and quads (unless you know if draw_texture_extention works well on ios?)  The transition between the pixel perfect splash screen and my texture'd copy doesn't look good.

Comment: To render my first open gl screen, I switch to orthogonal and try to match my background poly to the edges of the screen.  BUt I've always noticed some blurring.  Have you gotten this to work without any blurring, like a straight up pixel blit?  Maybe i'm miss-aligning by a pixel or two...